# C# Only set property when value is given

Tags: c#

I have a class with a full prop and the default value is already set

I was wondering if there was a way of only setting the value of the property if a value with given when crate a new instance of this class?

```
    public DateTime dStart { get; set; }
    private DateTime _dStop;

    public DateTime dStop
    {
        get { return _dStop; }
        set { _dStop = DateTime.Today; }
    }

    public UserControl1(DateTime dateStart, DateTime dateEnd)
    {
        // 
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

Creating an Instance of the class

`XtraForm test = new UserControl1(dateStart, optional Property);`

Comment: Aside from anything else, ignoring `value` within a property setter feels really odd. (I'd also very strongly recommend that you start following .NET naming conventions.)

Comment: I agree with @JonSkeet as `dStop` might be a `DoorStopDate`  or `DangerStopDate` but how do we know?  Names are hard.

Comment: Yeah these are good points just change the names to dateStop and dateStart

Comment: I would suggest `StopDate` and `StartDate` in fact. (Note the capitalization, for public members.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make it nullable, and set it `= null` in the parameter list. this makes it optional, and all optional parameters must always go at the end of the list.

```
public DateTime dStart { get; set; }
private DateTime _dStop;

public DateTime dStop
{
    get { return _dStop; }
    set { _dStop = DateTime.Today; }
}

public UserControl1(DateTime dateStart, DateTime? dateEnd = null)
{
    if (dateEnd.HasValue)
        _dStop = dateEnd.Value;
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

Usage:

1. `XtraForm test = new UserControl1(dateStart)`
2. `XtraForm test = new UserControl1(dateStart, dateEnd)`
3. `XtraForm test = new UserControl1(dateStart, dateEnd: dateEnd)`

Comment: or as a default parameter?
`, DateTime dateEnd = DateTime.Today`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Yes, that would be preferable for me. But in this case I was trying to adhere to his requirement: `only setting the value of the property if a value [was] given`

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss: That wouldn't compile - optional parameter default values have to be compile-time constants.

Comment: Yea, that was my 5 second response not well thought out :(

Answer (score 1):

You could make it a `private set` so that it can only be initialized via the constructor or exposing a method of the class to set it, which it doesn't sound like you want to, then add an extra constructor which only takes the `DateTime` start:

```
public DateTime dStart { get; set; }
private DateTime _dStop;

public DateTime dStop
{
    get { return _dStop; }
    private set { _dStop = value; }
}

public UserControl1(DateTime dateStart, DateTime dateEnd)
{
    //value was given, so set it
    dStop = dateEnd;
    // 
    InitializeComponent();
}

public UserControl1(DateTime dateStart)
{
    //in this instance you set it to some default value as the value was not given
    dStop = DateTime.Today;
    // 
    InitializeComponent();
}
```